# How can I solve this (convolution) integral?

Tags: control-system, convolution, lti-system

Let  \$x(t) = \sigma(t)\$  where  \$\sigma(t)\$  is the unit step function, and
\$h(t) = e^{-4t} \cdot \sigma(t)\$.  When I try to solve the convolution \$x(t) \ast h(t)\$, I get

$$ x(t) \ast h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sigma(\tau) \cdot \sigma(t-\tau) \cdot e^{-4(t-\tau)} d\tau $$
$$ = \int_{0}^{\infty}\sigma(t-\tau) \cdot e^{-4(t-\tau)} d\tau $$
$$ = \int_{0}^{t}e^{-4(t-\tau)} d\tau = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot e^{-4t}$$

According to my exercise sheet, the correct solution should be

$$ x(t) \ast h(t) = \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot e^{-4t}\right) \cdot \sigma(t) $$

Why is that? In which step did I forget something so that there is a step function in the solution?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's math and not necessarily specific to EE (as defined by this site as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3rd step, the integral from 0 to t includes negative values of t, but both starting signals are zero for negative t.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I do not understand it completely. The functions in the integral depend on tau, and with respect to tau they are zero for negative tau. What is the meaning of t in the integral (mathematically)? Why does that have to be zero for negative t?

Comment: t is just t. You have \$\sigma(\tau) \sigma(t)\$ (ignoring the difference to \$\tau\$ for a moment) under the integral, which is zero for \$t \le 0\$ or \$\tau \le 0\$.